Where is the HOSTNAME taken from?
In the last few days the server name in the prompt on our production server has changed from the correct myu3a01 to the incorrect icaris30, the name of an old server which is now used to address our backup NAS.
We are running on Centos 6 (which we are working to replace).
The /etc/hosts file, /etc/hostname file,  /etc/sysconfig/network file all show the correct server name.
The ip address of icaris30 has been changed by the ISP recently, although I do not see any relevance of this.
The command hostname gives icaris30  and hostname -i gives its ip address. hostname -a gives the hosts file names for icaris30.
I am using ssh to access the server, which is the correct server, even though the prompt is incorrect.
How can I fix the displayed server name?
Where is it getting the incorrect name?

Is the server configured to use static IP or DHCP? Also, try grep -i icaris30 /root/.bash_history /var/log/audit/audit.log; maybe someone has accidentally typed a command like hostname icaris30.

I would check the DNS. If the entry is correct or if there is also a second with the old name. A possible leftover by changing something is the reverse entry (PTR). I would also check if this one is correct or if there are multiple entries.

the OS keeps a record of the hostname, and I think that's what the shells use. Linux should have the gethostname()/ sethostname() system calls to query and set it, which the hostname tool can do for you. I think it's usually set from the contents of /etc/hostname at some point during boot. Of course systemd has systemd-hostnamed.service and hostnamectl for that. But just hostname icaris30 as root would do to change it on a running system.

1.DHCP, I think. The grep gave grep: /root/.bash_history/var/log/audit//audit.log: Not a directory. I think it extremely unlikely that someone accidentally changed the hostname. As I said, all the files that I know of that contain the hostname show it as it aught to be, myu3a01 (or myu3a01.myu3a.net).

I do not seem to have sethostname or gethostname. If I just enter hostname it gives me the correct myu3a01.myu3a.net. if I enter hostname myu3a01 it then says that myu3a01 is the hostname. echo $HOSTNAME gives icaris30. Where is the environment variable HOSTNAME set? That may answer my problem, as that is used in setting the command prompt.
